# How come documentation in python is not showing up?

Tags: python, function, package, documentation

Let's consider very simple package with the following folder/file hierarchy:

```
package_tutorial (folder)
├── mypackage(folder)
   └── file.py
    └──__init__.py
```

In file.py I created very basic function with documentation:

```
def average(x,y):
        """ Calculate mean of two numbers
    Parameters
    ----------
    x,y: real numbers

    Returns
    -------
    average of x and y

    Examples
    --------
    average(2,4)

    """
        return (x+y)/2
```

My problem is:

```
import mypackage as mp 
mp.average(2,10)
6
```

However.. it seems that python doesn't see my created documentation...
`help(mp.average)` doesn't seem to work. What have I done incorrectly ?

**EDIT**

I think I found the problem. Documentation works from the .py file at the level of package_tutorial folder. However it doesn't work from any other location. Do you know how can I make my documentation visible to .py files opened from any location ?

**EDIT vol 2**

My `__init__.py` contains only one line:

```
from .file import *
```

**EDIT vol 3**
I used code :

```
import mypackage as mp
reload(mp)
help(mp.average)
```

But still I only see:

```
 Help on function average in module mypackage.file:

average(x, y)
```

Instead of whole created documentation

Comment: Was it already saved with the docstring when you first imported it?

Comment: Well.. I haven't saved any docstring manually. If it's created automatically where should I look after it ?

Comment: Huh? The docstring is in the code.

Comment: I included all code that is stored in file.py in question. Do you think that the problem is about omitting docstring  ?

Comment: The question is whether that code was already saved like that when you first imported it, or whether you edited that in afterwards. Would btw be helpful to show your `__init__.py` as well.

Comment: Ohh... now I understand sorry. So I created the function, I imported it and after everything I edited function by adding documentation.

Comment: Sounds like you should reload the module then.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by reloading a module ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload

Comment: Could you please have a look at the code ? I think the problem still exists even after reloading...

Comment: Maybe you need `mp = reload(mp)`. What happens if you change the code, for example remove the `/2` and reload again? Does that get updated (i.e., using it gives a different result) but the help still doesn't work?